# Issues with Python, Jupyter Lab, and Pip After Changing Drive Letter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, environment-variables, jupyter-lab, solid-state-drive

I recently installed a new SSD on my laptop and reorganized my drives. I moved all software from drive D to the new SSD, now named drive Z. I then merged the original drive D into drive C. However, I'm encountering issues with Python and its associated tools like Jupyter Lab and Pip, which were part of the moved software.

When I try to open Jupyter Lab using the command `jupyter lab`, I receive the following error:

[jupyter lab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53csA.png)

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"D:\python3.8.9\WPy64-3890\python-3.8.9.amd64\python.exe"  "Z:\python3.8.9\WPy64-3890\python-3.8.9.amd64\scripts\jupyter-lab.exe" ': ???????????,
```

Similarly, using `pip list` gives me this error:

[pip list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZxtb.png)

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"D:\python3.8.9\WPy64-3890\python-3.8.9.amd64\python.exe"  "Z:\python3.8.9\WPy64-3890\python-3.8.9.amd64\Scripts\pip.exe" list': ???????????
```

However, I can open Python and Spyder normally through the Command Prompt, and I've verified all my environment variables.

**Question:**

How can I resolve these issues and correctly point the system to the new Python executable path on drive Z? Is there a way to update the paths without reinstalling Python and all related packages?

- I searched "python" in regedit and changed all D:\ to Z:\
- I changed all env variables from D:\ to Z:\